# Adding an event handerler to a custom control

Tags: custom-controls, event-handling

I have a custom control i have created with a picture box, a label, and a combobox, i want to create a custom SelectedIndexChanged event handerler so i can perform actions when the index has been changed of the combobox, but with it being a custom control this event is not available to me by default, so im hoping i can create one.  custom controls and events are new to me.  any help would be apreciated, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to fire the event without telling which items are now selected you can do this with:

```
public event EventHandler SelectionChanged;

protected virtual void OnSelectionChanged() {
    if (SelectionChanged != null) {
        SelectionChanged(this, new EventArgs());
    }
}
```

just call `OnSelectionChanged()` within your control and the event `SelectionChanged` will be fired.

If you also want to tell which elements are now selected you can use the following, just replace `object[]` with your objectarray:

```
public event SelectionChangedEventHandler SelectionChanged;
public delegate void SelectionChangedEventHandler(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e);

protected virtual void OnSelectionChanged(object[] SelectedItems) {
    if (SelectionChanged != null) {
        SelectionChanged(this, new SelectionChangedEventArgs(SelectedItems));
    }
}

public class SelectionChangedEventArgs : EventArgs {
    public object[] SelectedItems { get; private set; }

    public SelectionChangedEventArgs(object[] SelectedItems) {
        this.SelectedItems = SelectedItems;
    }
}
```